# For $\frac{16x-3}{x^3+x} = \frac{bx+c}{x^2+1}+\frac{a}{x}$, what is a+b+c?

Tags: contest-math

I only got to getting rid of the denominator and turning the equation into 16x-3 = ax^2+a+bx^2+cx, but from that on I don't know what to do.

Comment: For the equation to be true for *all* real $x$, except for those which are not applicable, i.e., $x = 0$ due to it being used in $2$ denominators, what must the coefficients of each power of $x$ (including the $0$'th power, i.e., the constant) in your resulting equation be when they are all to one side of the equation with the other side being $0$?

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thank you! The coefficients must all be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange $16x-3 = ax^2+a+bx^2+cx$ into a standard-form quadratic equation.

$$(a + b) x^2 + (c - 16)x + (a + 3) = 0$$

Since this must be true *for all* $x$, all of the coefficients must be zero, i.e., $a + b = 0$, $c - 16 = 0$, and $a + 3 = 0$.  The solution is $a = -3, b = 3, c = 16$.